# Error:Illegal use of reserved keyword "if" (matlab)

Tags: matlab, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I have an error , the result is  Illegal use of reserved keyword `if` .Any help would be appreciated ,thanks in advance

```
 for i=(start_point+1) : (maximum_size-1)

        if   t(i,2)<starty 

            {

            if  t(i-1,1) == t(i,1)  ||  t(i-1,2) == t(i,2) 

                sum1 = sum1+1;

            else
                sum1 = sum1+sqrt(2);
            end

            }


        elseif   t(i,2)==starty && f(i,1)>= maximum_size*0.5

               {

              if  t(i-1,1) ==t(i,1) || t(i-1,2)==t(i,2)
                sum1 = sum1+1;
                m=i;
            else
                sum1 = sum1+sqrt(2);
                m=i;
              end
              }
        else 
            continue

        end

    end
```

Comment: Get rid of the `{}`.  In the future, please [RTFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM): http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/specialcharacters.html

Answer (score 1):

It's easy - you can't use `{}` in matlab alike C.

`{ }`  Braces are used to form cell arrays.  They are similar to
      brackets `[ ]` except that nesting levels are preserved.

```
  {magic(3) 6.9 'hello'} is a cell array with three elements.

  {magic(3),6.9,'hello'} is the same thing.  

  {'This' 'is' 'a';'two' 'row' 'cell'} is a 2-by-3 cell array.
```

The semicolon ends the first row. `{1 {2 3} 4}` is a 3 element
      cell array where element 2 is itself a cell array.

Braces are also used for content addressing of cell arrays.
      They act similar to parentheses in this case except that the
      contents of the cell are returned.

Some examples:

`X{3}` is the contents of the third element of `X`.

`X{3}(4,5)` is the (4,5) element of those contents.

`X{[1 2 3]}` is a comma-separated list of the first three
         elements of `X`.  It is the same as `X{1},X{2},X{3}` and makes sense
         inside `[]`,`{}`, or in function input or output lists (see LISTS).

You can repeat the content addressing for nested cells so
      that `X{1}{2}` is the contents of the second element of the cell
      inside the first cell of `X`.

This also works for nested
      structures, as in `X(2).field(3).name` or combinations of cell arrays
      and structures, as in `Z{2}.type(3)`.

Just delete `{}` and try again

Comment: thanks a lot! i was confused with c ,you are right :) thanks